# Where is security.h?

Tags: security, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04`. I am trying to write a program using  `<security.h>` but `gcc` cannot find it. I want to know how to include it. Also it is not present in my include folder. Any suggestions how to use `<security.h>` or which option to turn on in make menuconfig to include it?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure the kernel-headers are present. It should be `linux/security.h` (in the sytem includes).

Comment: I have a fresh Ubuntu install but I didn't find it in linux/ any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the Kernel headers,

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's under

> /usr/src/linux-headers-***/include/linux/security.h

where *** is your used kernel version numbers.

I suggest to find it if you're not sure using

```
sudo find / -name "security.h"
```

Check which kernel you're running first

```
uname -srm
```